# Crystal-lang httpget basic_auth

Tags: crystal-lang

I am writing some code in Ruby... But I can't figure out how basic authentication works with Crystal-lang.

In ruby I had to always use request.basic_auth but that probably doesn't work in Crystal lang. 
What am I doing ruby? Could someone write that line request.basic_auth in Crystal-lang?

```
    request = HTTP::Client.get "http://127.0.0.1:#{ports[coinName]}/"
    request.basic_auth username([coinName], password[coinName])
    json = JSON.parse(request.body
```

error

```
in ./src/coinHashRate.cr:29: undefined method 'basic_auth' for HTTP::Client::Response

    request.basic_auth username[coinName], password[coinName]
            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do:

```
require "http/client"

client = HTTP::Client.new "127.0.0.1", ports[coinName]
client.basic_auth(username[coinName], password[coinName])
client.get "/"
```

You configure the client with basic auth, not the request nor the response.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same as ruby. Are you getting any errors when you run it?

[Here is a link to the original source of the function for clarification](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/5b3c9dc1dbdd5077f036f76830b23b1142a9c445/src/http/client.cr#L176)

Using the new function instead of get.

```
request = HTTP::Client.new "http://127.0.0.1/", ports[coinName]
request.basic_auth username[coinName], password[coinName]
response = request.get "/"
json = JSON.parse response.body
```

Comment: Just to follow up, would you be able to select an answer for future users with this question?

Comment: I haven't got it working yet. I will select an answer or post my own when I figure out what I am doing wrong. It can't parse the json for now it seems.

Comment: That's understandable, sorry. What error is it giving now?